# Are auto manufacturer lease promotions the same as money-factor promotions?

Tags: auto-leasing

Car manufacturers often run lease promotions in which they quote a lease cost ($X down and $Y/month) for a particular vehicle model.  We know that the total cost to lease a car is a function of three variables:

1. Purchase price
2. Residual value
3. Money factor (i.e., interest rate)

I've never approached a car dealer with one of those promotions so I can't tell: Which of those variables, if any, is being promoted by the car manufacturer?

I gather that *in general* residual value and money factor are essentially fixed by the manufacturer's leasing arm, so that the only variable that one can negotiate with a dealer is the purchase price.  (It is to the buyer's benefit to know which variable is being subsidized by a manufacturer promotion so that the dealer can't hide that during negotiation.)  So how does a buyer correctly incorporate the manufacturer's lease promotion into the negotiation?  Does the promotion show up as a reduced money factor?  Or a credit on the purchase price?  Or an elevated residual value?

Comment: I'm dubious about `1. Purchase price`.  More likely, it's `1. Their cost`.

Comment: @RonJohn: The three variables together determine the cost of a lease.  A transaction can occur at a purchase price below the dealer's cost to obtain the vehicle.  Dealers are known to agree to sell vehicles at a loss for various reasons.

Comment: Selling at a loss is how you go out of business.  Dealerships know their costs, and know what "kick backs" they get from the loan companies and the manufacturers.